# Can we delete project.json file?

Tags: msbuild, visual-studio-2015

I just created a new project file. There is a project.lock.json file. Can we delete it?

Does it affect the build if my codes checked in without it?

Answer (score 0):

Yes, you can delete it.

If you delete the 'project.lock.json' file, inside of Visual Studio. a new one will be created, based on the 'project.json' file.

I just deleted one because somehow it got corrupted. Instantly VS 2015 created a new one.

it wouldn't hurt to include this file if you have continuous integration/build server.

I hope it helps.